# Limit of a bivariate function

Tags: real-analysis

Can some one help myself to compute the limit of the following bivariate function
$f(x,y)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}$ when $(x,y)$ converges to the vector $(0,1)$

Thank you a lot
computer science researcher

Answer (score 0):

Solution is $0$.

Let's assume that $y$ is not zero. Then,

$0\leq \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}} \leq \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ and when $x\to 0$ it is $0$.

Also, if $y=0$, you have $\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ which is again $0$, when $x\to 0$.

Comment: The inequality in the 3-rd line is not correct.